# Multilevel Nested Query - RequestError Exception 400 - Failed to create query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am using Elasticsearch 5.1.1. While doing a nested query, it is returning 400 Error

My Doc will look like this

```
{
"_index" : "test",
"_type" : "test_five",
"_source" : {
  "doc" : {
    "keyword_elas" : "elasticsearch",
    }
  },
  "doc_as_upsert" : true }
```

This is my Query Code

```
 {
"query": {
    "nested": {
        "path":"_source",
        "query": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "_source.doc",
                "query": {
                    "match": {
                        "_source.doc.keyword_elas": "elasticsearch"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

For the above Query i got an exception

> elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400,
>   u'search_phase_execution_exception', u'failed to create query: {\n
>   "nested" : {\n "query" : {\n "nested" : {\n

Is this an exception due to some Query Mistake ? or any Version problem...

Thank You

Comment: The bottom of my error message had a specific `reason` property which told me I failed to create the nested type properly (when setting up my mappings):
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "illegal_state_exception",
        "reason": "[nested] nested object under path [comments] is not of nested type"
      }

Answer (score 4):

I am not quite sure why you're using a nested query in this environment.

If I have a document like this :

```
{
"_index" : "test",
"_type" : "test_five",
"_source" : {
  "doc" : {
    "keyword_elas" : "elasticsearch",
    }
  },
  "doc_as_upsert" : true }
```

And my goal is to match the `keyword_elas` field. All I would do is :

```
GET test/test_five/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "keyword_elas" : "elasticsearch"
        }
    }
}
```

Exact Matches :

**Analyzed field :**

```
 GET test/test_five/_search
    {
        "query": {
            "match" : {
                "keyword_elas" : "elasticsearch",
                 "fuzziness": "0"

            }
        }
    }
```

Note : If you have a document in `keyword_elas` that contains `elasticsearch ABC` , this query will work because it will be zero fuzziness on the first token (`elasticsearch`).

For `not analyzed fields` (fully exact match)

```
GET test/test_five/_search
 {
  "query": {
    "term" : { "keyword_elas" : "elasticsearch" } 
  }
}
```

If you have two documents in your index with

```
keyword_elas : elasticsearch
```

and

```
keyword_elas : elasticsearch abc
```

The term query will only match the first document.

Comment: Hello Yeikel, i agree to this. If you want exact match query - what will be your answer ?

Comment: Is your field analyzed or not analyzed?

Comment: for me first case is also throwing an exception. In the second case if the value of the field is  '"keyword_elas" : "elasticsearch term"' - even search elasticsearch is returning result. I want it like if and only if am searching "elasticsearch term" it should return the result.

Comment: If so , you need to have a non analyzed field and use the term query. An analyzed field will work as you explain. Can you post your mapping?

Comment: '{
  "test" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "test_five" : {
        "properties" : {
          "doc" : {
            "properties" : {
              "keyword_elas" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }}}},"doc_as_upsert" : {"type" : "boolean"},"keyword_elas" : {"type" : "text", "fields" : {

Comment: the above is the mapping of the doc

Comment: Change the mapping of keyword_elas to keyword instead of text type:"keyword" and try again

Comment: for updating the mapping? we need to reindex the whole mapping ryt ? can you help me remap in Elasticsearch 5.1 ?

Comment: search using query - term is not working. My case is like this the value of keyword_elas is "elasticsearch abc" - so for that while am searching {"query":{"term":{"keyword_elas":"elasticsearch abc"}}} is not return anything but {"query":{"term":{"keyword_elas":"elasticsearch"}}} is returning the documents i wanted.

Comment: @RahulBabuR 1) Delete your index 2) Update the mapping 3) Re index the data 4) Try the term query on the non analyzed field.